# Azure DevOps pre-deployment cannot find path of ARMTemplateForFactory.json

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have a deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps which was working, but not anymore.
Anytime that I excecute the deployment pipeline, the pre-deployment script fails with the following error.

2021-03-05T12:00:12.4932594Z ##[error]Cannot find path 'D:\a\r1\a\psdf-df-dev\ARMTemplateForFactory.json' because it does not exist.

These are my script arguments:

-armTemplate $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/psdf-df-dev/ARMTemplateForFactory.json -ResourceGroupName psdf-rg-$(Environment) -DataFactoryName psdf-df-$(Environment) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false

I hope that somebody can help!

Comment: Hi @Rnz0r, how are things going? have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please have a try with it, and any update, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the script arguments you shared, you store the file "**ARMTemplateForFactory.json**" in the source repository, right?

If so, before executing the pre-deployment script, you should make sure:

- the file "**ARMTemplateForFactory.json**" is existing in the latest version of the source code that you want to deploy. And its relative path is "**psdf-df-dev/ARMTemplateForFactory.json**" in the repository.
- the latest source code have been downloaded into the specified directory "**$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)**".

If  the issue still exists, for us to investigate this issue further, please share us with the complete debug logs of the successful and failed deployment pipeline runs.

Comment: Hi Bright Ran! Thank you a lot for your feedback. I was storing the file in another folder then specified:

The file was in -armTemplate $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/psdf/psdf-df-dev/ARMTemplateForFactory.json

and I looked for the file in -armTemplate $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/psdf-df-dev/ARMTemplateForFactory.json

I changed the path in the script arguments and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Rnz0r, glad that the problem has been solved. could you please mark my answer as the solution of this topic if it is helpful to you to solve the problem? This may be also very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar problems. Of course, you also can post an answer with the summary of the problem and your solution, and then mark the answer as the solution. Thanks.